# How and where is the at command configured?

Tags: centos, email, at

When I install a new Linux system, one of my first tasks is to have crontab send all its email to a designated email address, not root. I want to do the same for the `at` command.

That is I would like the `at` command to send its *job concluded* email to a different email than the user who invoked the at command.

However, I cannot find where `at` is configured. I have been poking around my CentOS 6.4 system to no avail.

Comment: "a pointer would be appreciated" -- pun intended? :)

Comment: No pun intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CentOS `at` configuration file is in `/etc/sysconfig/atd`

according to the man page, the mail notification is as follows:

> If  the file /var/run/utmp is not available or corrupted, or if the
>   user is not logged on at the time at
>          is invoked, the mail is sent to the userid found in the environment variable LOGNAME.  If that is  undefined or empty, the current userid is assumed.

One suggestion would be to edit /etc/aliases, and assign your local user a different email address. Doing that would allow `at`'s mail to be redirected the way you intend.

Comment: This looks like email cannot be re-directed. Based on your answer, I tried a few things, and my local user still got the email. My original question becomes a different question about redirecting mail. Thanks.

Comment: /etc/aliases worked, but don't forget to "sudo newaliases"

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, the 'at' command is missing entirely and the package needs to be installed.  Look for the at.x86_64 or at_i386, at_i486, at_i586 packages.

Both OEL71 and CentOS can add it with:

yum -y install

e.g.:  yum -y install at.x86_64

If you try copying the commands from another host, you will get pam authentication errors when run by anything other than root.

Comment: This answers a question the OP didn't ask.

Comment: the behavior the OP asked for happens by default.  "at" emails the user who configured "at" jobs by default, not root unless root set up the "at" job in question.  So I thought that perhaps "atd" was not actually installed on their system.

Answer (score 0):

In many vendor releases, the 'at' functionality is not appropriate initialized, you may have to activate the /etc/init.d programming for the at command.

How it works is that is basically piggy-backs its work using different files, but usually the crond daemon handles this operation.  However, on some implementations a special at daemon is present just to handle all the at commands.